# How do I install Python3 under alpine linux with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, alpine-linux

My vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "alpine/alpine64"
end
```

Pretty simple. `vagrant up && vagrant ssh` gets me into the box.

Unfortunately, that's about the last thing that goes right:

```
alpine:~$ sudo apk add python3
(1/8) Installing libbz2 (1.0.6-r6)
(2/8) Installing libcrypto1.1 (1.1.1a-r1)
ERROR: libcrypto1.1-1.1.1a-r1: trying to overwrite etc/ssl/openssl.cnf owned by libressl2.6-libcrypto-2.6.4-r0.
(3/8) Installing expat (2.2.6-r0)
(4/8) Installing libffi (3.2.1-r6)
(5/8) Installing gdbm (1.13-r1)
(6/8) Installing sqlite-libs (3.26.0-r3)
(7/8) Installing libssl1.1 (1.1.1a-r1)
(8/8) Installing python3 (3.6.7-r0)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r8.trigger
1 error; 171 MiB in 59 packages
alpine:~$ python3
Error relocating /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0: getrandom: symbol not found
```

For some reason, libcrypto and libressl just aren't very good friends.

How do I get Python3 installed on alpine linux?

Comment: Which Alpine version? It may be a musl dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [Alpine vagrant image v3.7.0](https://app.vagrantup.com/alpine/boxes/alpine64/versions/3.7.0) which you tried to use was created 10 month ago. It is slightly outdated. That's why you faced some dependency issues. `world` should be updated first in order to install `python3` package there, so:

```
alpine:~$ sudo apk upgrade
..........................
alpine:~$ sudo apk add python3
..............................
alpine:~$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Nov  7 2018, 21:49:03) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an [Alpine box with python 3 already installed](https://app.vagrantup.com/alainvanhoof/boxes/alpine-virtual-x86_64-3.6) Or check how it's built, anyway